# memory problems with large file download from WCF SOAP service to JAVA client

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, soap, heap-memory

We currently have an existing WCF SOAP service that runs fine with a large range of clients.  We present a StreamBody as a way to download larger filesets.  I have tried virtually every way to attempt to download large files without loading the file completely into memory by the client.  I have in every attempt.  Essentially, by calling the following, the JAVA client wants to load the complete file into memory.  I am looking for suggestions.  Below is my latest attempt:

```
OrderServiceStub stub = getOrderServiceStub();
OrderServiceStub.GetStreamedOrderOutputRequestMessage getStreamedOrderOutputRequestMessage = new OrderServiceStub.GetStreamedOrderOutputRequestMessage();
OrderServiceStub.GetStreamedOrderOutputRequest getStreamedOrderOutputRequest = new OrderServiceStub.GetStreamedOrderOutputRequest();

for (OrderServiceStub.OrderOutput o : orderoutput.getOrderOutput()){
        OrderServiceStub.Guid guidOutput = o.getOrderOutputTicket();
        String fileName = o.getOrderOutputName();
        getStreamedOrderOutputRequest.setOrderOutputTicket(guidOutput);
        getStreamedOrderOutputRequestMessage.setGetStreamedOrderOutputRequest(getStreamedOrderOutputRequest);
        int bufferSize = 1024;

        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(stub.getStreamedOrderOutput(getStreamedOrderOutputRequestMessage).getFileData().getStreamBody().getInputStream());
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\temp\\" + fileName));  

        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(is, os);
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't. `IOUtils.copyLarge(InputStream in, OutputStream out)` uses a buffer of 4k. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the whole thing via apache, you might try putting it into a loop, reading your bufferSize, then flushing the output stream. Then continue, doing the same. Hopefully that will help.